# Django-CMS - Django Model Form not rendering

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-cms

I'm building a new site in Django with Django-CMS that needs a form to filter JSON results and return the filtered set.

My issue is that, initially, I can't even get the Django Model Form to render yet I can get the CSRF token to work so the form is technically rendering, but the inputs/fields aren't showing up at all.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from .jobs.jobs import *

roles = get_filters()

loc = roles[0]
j_type = roles[1]
industry = roles[2]

class Filter(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    job_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    search = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

jobs/jobs.py

```
try:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib3 
import json 

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

def get_filters():

    response = http.request('GET', 'http://206.189.27.188/eo/api/v1.0/jobs')

    jobs = json.loads(response.data.decode('UTF-8'))

    job_list = []

    for job, values in jobs.items():
        job_list.append(values)

    roles_data = []

    for job in job_list[0]:
        roles_data.append(job)

    roles_data = sorted(roles_data, key=lambda role : role["id"], reverse=True)

    loc = []
    j_type = []
    industry = []

    for role in roles_data:
        loc.append(role['location'])
        j_type.append(role['type'])
        industry.append(role['industry'])

    return loc, j_type, industry
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import FilterForm

def index(request):
    form = FilterForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    } 
    return render(request, 'blog.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Filter

class FilterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Filter
        fields = ['country', 'job_type', 'industry', 'search']
```

urls.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals

from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.views.static import serve

from . import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap,
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^accounts/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^services/latest-roles/', views.filter_form, name="filter_form" )
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        ] + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns
```

blog.html

```
{% extends 'includes/templates/layout.html' %}
{% load cms_tags i18n sekizai_tags zinnia %}

{% block main_content %}
    {% include 'components-header-image.html' %}

    <section class="module">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 m-auto text-center">
                            <form action="POST" class="col-md-12">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ form.as_p }}
                                <button name="submit" class="btn btn-brand">Search</button>
                            </form>
                            {% get_all_roles%}
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="space" data-MY="120px"></div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 flex-center text-center">
                            {% placeholder 'jobs-bottom-statement' %} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </section>


          <!-- Image-->
          {% include 'components-contact.html' %}

          <!-- Image end-->
{% endblock %}
```

Sorry for the masses of information, just wanted to include anything anyone might need.

As I said, the CSRF token is displaying, nothing is throwing an error anywhere but it's just not displaying the fields at all.

Really appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: If you inspect the page or view source, what gets rendered where you expect to see the form?

Comment: Nothing from the form at all. The CSRF token is there but nothing else.

Comment: Ok, and are you connecting your app to a CMS page with an Apphook? It's not explicitly declared in the URLs so you'd need to connect it though a CMS page.

Comment: Originally I'd set it through the url at: `url(r'^services/latest-roles/', views.filter_form, name="filter_form" )` but that didn't seem to help or be right although I'm not sure why but I think I was being an idiot, the view is named index so that should be what's rendered not the form name.

Comment: Yeah I don't think your view is being called. You'd need to have `views.index` if you wanted to hardcode the URL for the index view above. Then the next job is dealing with `get` and `post` methods in the view.

Comment: Hi again, sorry it's so much later than before but I was taken off of this project briefly and am now back on it and still having the same issue. No matter what I do, even with the view name changed, the form doesn't render. I've even followed a very basic tutorial to implement a simple form and run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 95% sure your view isn't being called.

You need to integrate your application as a CMS apphook or hard code your URLs into your root `urls.py` which is the easier integration test as it doesn't depend on CMS integration.

So Add your view to your URLs like this;

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^blog/$', views.index, name='blog'),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

Then go to `localhost:8000/blog/` in your browser & you should hit your view.

To confirm you're hitting it you could make a simple amendment to your view;

```
def index(request):
    form = FilterForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    } 
    print "index hit"
    return render(request, 'blog.html', context)
```

Then you'll see "index hit" in your console if your view is called.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. It turns out the view wasn't being called and no matter what I did with adding in the url it didn't get called. In the end I had to create an Apphook for it. I'm still not 100% sure why it didn't work seeing as even the guys at Divio said it should be as simple as adding a Django form but, hey, it's working! Thanks again!